# Java Period.between shows strange output

Tags: java, localdate

I am making an application just for learning purpose. And I tried to calculate the difference between two dates

```
LocalDate today  = LocalDate.now();
LocalDate localHoudbaarheid = houdbaarheidsDatum;
Period period = Period.between(today, localHoudbaarheid);
```

The calculation works, but the output is strange.

Output of the code:

```
Dagen tot over de datum: P9D
```

The only thing that should be shown is the `9` without the `P` and `D`. This is where I call the name period in my code to print it out:

```
"Dagen tot over de datum: " + period;
```

Comment: What is the value of `houdbaarheidsDatum`? Which output did you expect? `"P9D"` is the string representation of a **P**eriod with length 9 **D**ays.

Answer (score 5):

There is nothing whatsoever strange about the output, it is exactly what the **documentation**, i.e. the javadoc of [`Period.toString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Period.html#toString--) says it is:

> Outputs this period as a `String`, such as `P6Y3M1D`.
>
> The output will be in the **ISO-8601** period format. A zero period will be represented as zero days, `'P0D'`.

As documentation says, the output is following the [**ISO-8601 *standard***](https://www.iso.org/iso-8601-date-and-time-format.html) for durations, as also explained on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations):

> Durations define the amount of intervening time in a time interval and are represented by the format P[n]Y[n]M[n]DT[n]H[n]M[n]S ...

> - *P* is the duration designator (for *period*) placed at the start of the duration representation.
>
>   - *Y* is the year designator that follows the value for the number of years.
>   - *M* is the month designator that follows the value for the number of months.
>   - *W* is the week designator that follows the value for the number of weeks.
>   - *D* is the day designator that follows the value for the number of days.

Comment: Well, it should be noted that negative periods do NOT follow ISO-8601-specification. Example: `Period.of(2, 3, 1).negated().toString()` produces `P-2Y-3M-1D` instead of the more natural expression `-P2Y3M1D`.  Latter one is also not really defined in ISO itself but exists in a XML-Schema-subset of ISO-8601. This deviation from standard is an invention inherited by JodaTime.

Answer (score 4):

`P9D` means a **P**eriod of 9 **D**ays.

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.Period;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
        LocalDate after9Days = today.plusDays(9);
        Period period = Period.between(today, after9Days);
        System.out.println(period);
        System.out.printf("Years: %d, Months: %d, Days: %d", period.getYears(), period.getMonths(), period.getDays());
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
P9D
Years: 0, Months: 0, Days: 9
```

Learn more about it at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations

Comment: Not that days are "rounded down". That means that 23 hours will shows 0 days (which might or might not be what OP expects)

Answer (score 4):

The `toString()` method of `Period` outputs something like:

```
P(nbYears)Y(nbMonths)M(nbDays)D
```

`P9D` means a period of 9 days. `P4Y3M9D` means a period of 4 years, 3 months, and 9 days.

[The `Period` class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Period.html) has utility methods to get this information: `getDays()`, `getMonths()`, and `getYears()`.

If you just want to obtain the difference in the unit you choose, prefer using the `until()` method on [the Temporal interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/temporal/Temporal.html#until(java.time.temporal.Temporal,java.time.temporal.TemporalUnit)).

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
        LocalDate after3Months9Days = today.plusMonths(3).plusDays(9);
        System.out.println(today.until(after3Months9Days, ChronoUnit.DAYS));
    }
}
```

This outputs:

```
101
```